# savedInstanceState - visibility changes not restored?

Tags: android, android-activity

From what I read that the Activity will automatically save the state of Views and things like `EditText` and `TextView` restore their state automatically.

Does this not apply to the visibility?

For example:
If by default in the XML, I have a `TextView` that is visible. 
If I programatically set the textview to `GONE` using `tvInput.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

If the activity is recreated, the `tvInput` is not maintained as `GONE` it is now visible when it should not be.

Is this expected behavior? Do I need to be handling view visibility myself?

Comment: Having exact same issue. The changed value of an EditText is stored and restored but not changed visibility. I ended up restoring visibility in onRestore... Have not read a lot of documentation on this and is fairly rusty when it comes to android dev, I assume there are some logic to this...

Answer (score 0):

Did you set an id for your TextView, in your XML file? Only views with id's will have their state automatically restored.
Additionally, if you are overriding onSaveInstanceState(...) and/or onRestoreInstanceState(...), don't forget to start by calling the method of the superclass:

```
super.onSaveInstanceState(...);

super.onRestoreInstanceState(...);
```

Remember also that in onCreate(...) your views are not yet restored. They only get restored later.

Comment: Yes, I must have ids for them as I am programmatically setting them to `View.GONE`. I do call the `super.onSaveInstanceState`, but I do not have the restore instance method overridden so it should call the super method.

Comment: Having exact same issue. Changed value of EditText is stored and restored but no changed visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but this could be useful to anyone who wants to manually store and restore visibility state of views.

```
fun Bundle.saveVisibility(vararg views: View) {
    views.forEach { view ->
        putInt(view.id.toString(), view.visibility)
    }
}

fun Bundle.restoreVisibility(vararg views: View) {
    views.forEach { view ->
        if (containsKey(view.id.toString())) {
            view.visibility = getInt(view.id.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
     savedInstanceState?.restoreVisibility(*viewDataBinding.inputViews.toTypedArray())
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.saveVisibility(*viewDataBinding.inputViews.toTypedArray())
    }

private val FragmentGroupCreateDepositsBinding.inputViews: List<View>
    get() = listOf(tilSharePrice, tilFlatAmount, tilMinAmount, tilMaxAmount, tvRequiredHint, llRangeAmount)
```